# how to session()->forget('cart') for another user in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-session

my session driver is set to database,

.env => `SESSION_DRIVER=database`

I have made a model for session and I access to a session of another user by user_id like this :

```
use App\Models\Session;

$payload = Session::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->pluck('payload');
$payload = unserialize(base64_decode($payload));
if (!isset($payload['cart'])) {
    dd($payload['cart']);
}
```

now I want to `session()->forget('cart')` of that specific user not the current user, but the `payload` field is decode by base64 and serialized.

how to do that?

thanks

Comment: I don't think there is anything to do that in laravel, i think you will have to update the database

Comment: I just need to convert `$payload` array to `serialize(base64_encode($payload)` and save it in session model

Comment: I think it's the only option to save it back in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I found it.
the problem is to displacement of `serialize()` and `base64_encode()` after `unset($payload['cart'])` like this:

```
use App\Models\Session;

$session = Session::where('user_id', $request->user_id)->first();
$payload = unserialize(base64_decode($session->payload));
if (!isset($payload['cart'])){
    unset($payload['cart']);
}
$session->payload = base64_encode(serialize($payload));
$session->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few things and by changing the id it works :

```
// Get the store from laravel (encrypted or not)
$store = session()->getDrivers()['database'];
// Change the id
$store->setId($id);
// Start the session
$store->start();
// Remove the item
$store->pull('cart');
// Save the session in database
$store->save();
```

i don't think it's something that laravel support, so this might break in the future